# What are some ways to use the second brake lever on a bike with no back brake?

Tags: road-bike, brakes

I have a road bike with only front brakes and drop handlebars.

I've tried to install a bell that rings when you pull the lever and it became functional, but I decided to get rid of it as it had to be placed in the middle of the handlebar because it would pull on the wire I used when I would physically steer the handlebar (which was an awkward position)

TL;DR: What are some creative ideas for putting the second brake lever to use? An example would be to have it activate an LED that I could put at the front of my bike

Comment: If you're so concerned about pedestrian safety that you want to install a bell, why not install proper frickin' brakes on your bike? Just a thought...

Comment: Check your local road laws - in many western places a bicycle is required to have two functional and separate braking systems installed on the bike and working correctly.

Comment: "What are some ways...?" questions fundamentally fail to meet the mission of Stack Exchange sites, which are reserved only for questions which can be *specifically* answered.

Answer (score 5):

I politely suggest that you use the second brake lever to control a brake.

Bicycles are simple machines, subject to wear and tear.  And over time things get worn.

Some day your only brake may not operate satisfactorily , whether it be from gradual wear, lack of maintenance, sudden failure of a component, poor reassembly after some other work like a puncture fix, or even vandalism.

That will be the moment you wish for a second independent brake.  And dragging your feet on the ground is a poor substitute.

So the only reasonable and safe suggestion for your question is to (re)fit the back brake, and cable to the existing second brake lever.

Comment: The worst nightmare is a brake cable that breaks. I had that several times already. It's an instant loss of all braking power. If you don't have a backup in such a situation, you are doomed.

Comment: @cmaster I'll raise you my incident just over a week ago. Both cable disc brakes jammed off. I was descending a mountain pass cautiously, let the brakes off for a moment, and they would go back on. I believe hot pads seized in the calipers. Strange wear pattern on front moving pad - backing clearly hit rotor. Broken shoulder, surgery next week

Comment: @cmaster - And then there's simply forgetting to reconnect the cable after a road-side tire repair.